# Pandas - Propagating variance

Tags: python, pandas

For data of the form

```
mean            var             count
31.5910645161   747.570011484   310
45.7            350.0658        2
77.2548205128   4968.46005809   195
166.830361446   13755.5734253   166
40.29           208.8968        2
254.35          15204.1922      2
4.81            0.0             1
56.0124200913   962.697805171   1533
114.25          0.0             1
24.12           422.257129412   18
```

Where there a many more repetitions of count later. I need to `groupby('count').agg('mean','var')` in order to propagate the variance properly. However, that code does not work (mean and var don't know what to do with the 2 columns), and of course just using mean is out of the question (the mean of the variance is not the variance of the mean). How do you do this such that the variance gets sent forward properly?

Comment: How do you justify computing the mean and variance of variance? You cannot just propagate variances forward. Try it out mathematically, write the formula of variance, and try to compute the variance of a bunch of the variance formulae, and see if you can derive the variance formula of the whole group from there.

Comment: @Kartik  Mean is just number, The value of doing the has some meaning depending how its used.

Comment: @Merlin, no qualms about mean. You cannot take the mean and variance of variance and expect it to hold over all samples. There are complex methods of combining variances. This problem always occurs in bootstraping, jackknifing and similar statistical techniques. In other words, mean and variance of sample means holds, but mean and variance of sample variances is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> arg : function or dict
>     Function to use for aggregating groups. If a function, must either
>     work when passed a DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply. If
>     passed a dict, the keys must be DataFrame column names.
>
>     Accepted Combinations are:
>       - string cythonized function name
>       - function
>       - list of functions
>       - dict of columns -> functions
>       - nested dict of names -> dicts of functions
> ```

You passed two strings when you needed to pass a list of strings.

```
df.groupby('count').agg(['mean','var'])
```

[image]

Comment: This fixes it from an execution standpoint (in that it runs), but how do you interpret this? Obviously the Var mean has no meaning, but what do you do with the mean var (which is just the var of the previous mean) and the var of the var, or possibly with previous var and some operations with the new var.

Comment: @Elliot the interpretation depends on the domain.  There is meaning to variance of variance in the right context.  Means of means as well.  However, that is not topical for stackoverflow.  This is a question and answer site about coding.  Not interpretations of abused statistics.